# Including <iframe> and <script> tags with mezzanine_pagedown

Tags: django, python-3.x, markdown, mezzanine, pagedown

I'm using [mezzanine_pagedown](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/wiki/PageDown) to produce RichTextPages in my Mezzanine project, but even though I have `RICHTEXT_FILTER_LEVEL = 3` in my `settings.py`, I find that my manually-inserted `<script>` and `<iframe>` tags still get stripped. How do I configure PageDown to allow me to include these?

Other tags such as `<p>` and `<div>` get included without any problem, so it seems like these potentially more dangerous ones are being removed by pagedown's own filtering.

I should clarify for the sake of whoever silently downvoted this question that I am the sole administrator of my project, so I'm not worried about the security of allowing these tags in my pages because I produce all the content myself.

Comment: You may find this useful: http://grokbase.com/t/gg/mezzanine-users/1354t7bjyx/tinymce-strips-script-element

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved this by putting a `defaults.py` in a custom 'app' folder (I just have an empty folder with `defaults.py` and some templates I put there earlier)

So this becomes:

```
from mezzanine.conf import register_setting

register_setting(
     name="RICHTEXT_ALLOWED_TAGS",
     append=True,
     default=("script","iframe"),
)
```

This solution is largely based on the [official docs](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/configuration.html) and [this thread](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/mezzanine-users/1354t7bjyx/tinymce-strips-script-element).

EDIT: forgot to include iframe

Answer (score -1):

You can remove the template tags:

eg. in richtextpage.html

```
{{ page.richtextpage.content|richtext_filters|safe }}


{{ page.richtextpage.content }}
```

To stop all escaping.

Comment: This doesn't work: it just renders all my markup without turning it into HTML, except the `<script>` tags which it continues to escape to `&lt;script&gt;`